# Superimposing a landscape page with 90 degree rotation onto a landscape page with 0 rotation

Tags: c#, itext7

I have used the [superimpose example](https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/stamper/SuperImpose.java) to superimpose one pdf onto another. I am running into some trouble when trying to superimpose a page from a source file with a rotation of 90 degrees onto the destination page which has 0 rotation but is landscape (it's wider than it is tall).

When i first tried to stamp the content as in the example, it got the content rotated -90 as in the left example in the image below. When I tried to set the rotation of the destination page, the source content was placed in the right orientation but the destination page had turn (right example in the image below).

```
var sourcePageRotation = sourcePage.GetRotation();
destinationPage.SetRotation(sourcePageRotation);
```

How can I manipulate either the source or destination page to change the rotation value without actually changing the way it displays?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(As you referenced a Java example, I'll also refer to iText for Java.)*

In the [`SuperImpose`](https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/stamper/SuperImpose.java) example the pages to superimpose are added using

```
canvas.addXObject(page, 0, 0);
```

but there are other `PdfCanvas.addXObject` overloads, too, in particular

```
public PdfCanvas addXObject(PdfXObject xObject, float a, float b, float c, float d, float e, float f)
```

The 6 `float`s represent an affine transformation applied to the XObject, e.g. a rotation. Thus, you can rotate the imported page XObject from the source document to match the orientation of the destination document page, e.g. replace

```
canvas.addXObject(page, 0, 0);
```

by

```
canvas.addXObject(page, 0, 1, -1, 0, page.getHeight(), 0);
```

or, if that makes the page contents stand upside down, by

```
canvas.addXObject(page, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, page.getWidth());
```

Just like the example you referenced I here assume the lower left corner of the pages involved are the respective coordinate system origin. If that assumption is wrong, one needs to adapt the last two `float` parameters respectively  in the replacements above.

Comment: Thankyou for this @mkl, I actually already got there by finding your answer to a similar question using the `AffineTransform` function! I might add an answer of my own too as i had to write my own function to transform the annotation links on the same page, and I will link your answer in my question.